# How to get value from JS-Generated HTML inputs in PHP using POST or GET

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a grid of inputs using javascript. Each of these inputs has a unique name and id: "test1","test2"... I'm also able to change the style of these inputs based on their name.

```
var c = document.getElementById("gridOne");

function createTable() {
var table = document.createElement('table');
var rows = +document.getElementById('numRows').value;
var cols = +document.getElementById('numCols').value;
    var n = 0;
for(var r=0; r<rows; r++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(tr);
  for(var c=0; c<cols; c++) {
    if(r == 0 || c == 0 || r == rows - 1 ||c == cols - 1 ){ 
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        var inp = document.createElement('input');
        inp.setAttribute('id', 'test'+n);
        inp.setAttribute('name', 'test'+n);
        inp.setAttribute('value', n);
        inp.setAttribute('type','number');
        td.appendChild(inp);
        n++;


    } else {
        var tq = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(tq);
        tq.classList.add('inner');
        var inp = document.createElement('input');
        inp.setAttribute('type','text');
        inp.disabled = true;
        tq.appendChild(inp);
    }
  }

}
var container = document.getElementById('input_container');
container.innerHTML = '';
container.appendChild(table);
}
```

The HTML code that is handling and outputting the JavaScript is this

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="canvas" id="input_container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Grid1.js"></script>
</div>
<input name="Confirm" type="submit">
```

When i try to access the values submitted by these inputs i'm getting an error. I'm using PHP, ive tried both GET and POST but im getting no luck.

```
    if (isset($_POST['Confirm'])) 
{
    $test0 =  $_POST['test0'];
    $test1 =  $_POST['test1'];
    $test2 =  $_POST['test2'];
}
```

My code works for everything except the dynamically generated input forms.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Unidentified Index, test0

Comment: it is normal you have not input with the name test0 but your isset is working if you enter in the if

Comment: thats what i need help with

Comment: what is the value of rows and cols in your script use console .log or debug function of chrome

Comment: the value for these two inputs are user inputs, so they varies. That's why im creating the grid dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is *actually not an error*, but a **notice**.

> Undefined index: test0 in x on line y

To avoid that you should firstly check whether these values exists, i.e.:

```
$test0 = isset($_POST['test0']) ? $_POST['test0'] : 'default value';
```

Or using PHP7 [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce):

```
$test0 = $_POST['test0'] ?? 'default value';
```

## Better approach for your problem

I think that better way to handle dynamically generated fields would be to use arrays. So you should:

- use `[name]` attribute with braces `[]` at the end
- on the backend, iterate over that array.

So, example code might look like:

```
<input type="number" name="test[]">
<input type="number" name="test[]">
<input type="number" name="test[]">
```

and PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['test'] as $test) {
    var_dump($test);
}
```

Comment: how do i make the 'default value' be the user input?

Comment: Default value is when the user input isn't given.

Comment: THanks! this helped a lot